# Moderator declined the migration request with "you can delete this yourself"

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, migration, moderators

My request to migrate my question to stats.SE was declined with "you can delete this yourself". WTF? I didn't ask for deletion, I asked for migration! As far as I remember, it was never a problem, and I asked for lots of migrations! If it now becomes a problem and moderators don't want to deal with migratiton requests any more, then OK, but then high rep users should first be allowed to do that, as discussed here: [Shall migration be further tuned in the sense of moderation theory?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215148/166308)

[image]

Comment: There's not much difference between you deleting it and reasking on Stats, and a moderator migrating it. Unless you're really close to a question ban that one positively-scored, deleted question will tip you over the edge here? Not sure why this is an issue.

Comment: You can delete it yourself, and post it yourself on the site you want to migrate to. No need to involve mods, who have a lot to do that people can't handle themselves. Is that really a problem?

Comment: Sure, OP could have deleted and reposted themselves. But is it really too much asked for the moderator to do the migration and reply to the flag with "Migrated, but in the future please just delete and repost when possible"?

Comment: Yes it is a problem, my question got two upvotes, why would I delete it? Let alone the question ban mentioned by Tyler! We have migration here for a purpose, right? And if you argue with mods having too much work, then let's delegate it to high rep users.

Comment: Because it's fake internet points and means pretty much nothing? If you've identified that the question doesn't belong here, that's all you need to consider. Points and votes don't come into it.

Comment: At 35K rep you've no need to worry about a question ban, nor will 20 points here or there make any difference to you.

Comment: why would I have to spend another time to repost that question, when migration exist. Doesn't make sense. Then allow to migrate my own questions then.

Comment: Why would you have to spend time to post the question in the first place? You wouldn't, but you felt a need. Now you feel a need to move it. This is all you, you don't need help with it just because someone can physically help you with it

Comment: @Clive It's funny to me how the "rep means nothing" arguments always come from those with so much rep they stopped getting new benefits from it long ago, and a lot of the people who complain about it haven't unlocked all privileges associated with rep, and struggle to do so.

Comment: @TMS OK, so to be clear you don't want to lose 10 reputation points and that's why you've posted this question. FWIW, mods have a lot of stuff to do, and migration takes time and involves a process. Self-deletion and posting on Stats is something *you* can do. Therefore, by definition, it's something you ought to do.

Comment: @TMS Why should a moderator be taking time to do your own work for you just because you can't be bothered to?

Comment: As for the rep you're worried about losing, apparently *you asked your question on the wrong site*.  Frankly, you ought to be *losing* rep for doing that.  Be glad that you're going to come out even.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That would maybe be a statement worth examining, were we not talking about 2 measly votes here

Comment: @Clive Yes I agree in this case it doesn't matter at all

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It's worth noting that the reasons aren't necessarily what you might think.  Namely, the people that don't care about rep, and just care about posting quality content *tend to attract upvotes*.  People overly concerned with gaming the system, and not worried about producing quality content, *tend to struggle to attract upvotes*.  The people that don't care much about rep generally didn't care much about it when they had very little of it, but it's their attitude that is the *reason* they have so much, not the reverse. Also people motivated by rep tend to burn out quicker.

Comment: 'I asked for lots of migrations'...why do you keep posting on inappropriate sites?

Comment: Worth mentioning that moderators are *exception handlers*. In other words they will generally act when the community or OP is **unable** to manage the situation. That is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 26):

> *"why would I have to spend another time to repost that question, when migration exist"*.

<sub>(From a comment)</sub>

Why would anyone have to spend time migrating a question you asked yourself (having to determine if the question is migration worthy, if the target site you are suggesting really applies, maybe even consulting mods in the desired migration target) when you can easily re-ask the question in the appropriate site?

That the question received votes (up or down) is irrelevant. It's better if the correct audience judge the usefulness and clarity of your question.

Answer (score 15):

I declined the flag. Your question had no answers, which means you can delete it yourself and post it on another site.  You have a decent reputation which shows you should know that deleting a question without answers is perfectly ok.

Usually I use a decline response *"You can delete it and repost yourself. Check the help center of the other site before posting."*. That was my bad for not adding the extra part to the decline reason.

Moderators on Stack Overflow are domain specialists of what is on topic for Stack Overflow, not other sites. If a question has no answers, feel free to delete it. Check the faq of the other site and post the question there.

Moderator flags are supposed to be used to make actions that you cannot. For example, migrating a question that does have answers and *is* on topic for the target site. Be mindful: if a post is on topic on another site, it still may be on topic for Stack Overflow and may not  be migrated.

Unless a post is flagged by a high rep user on the proposed migration site, or it is obvious to the moderator it's on topic for the target site, moderators need to ask the other site if they want the post, a time consuming process. So it's not a flag to be used if you *can* (has no answers) delete your own post and make the investigation of whether it's on topic for the target site yourself.

Answer (score 5):

> ... if you argue with mods having too much work, then let's delegate it to high rep users.

This is already being done. There's a standard migration path to Stats.SE, so anyone with 3K rep or higher can vote to migrate questions there.

Generally, you should only ask moderators to do stuff that the community can't do itself. I'm not a moderator, but if I were and I had handled the flag, I would've declined it with the explanation that you should only flag stuff that actually requires moderator intervention.

Your point about reputation [is apparently basically correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges), except that the reputation will be transferred to the new site instead (so you'd lose the reputation on SO, but gain it on Stats.SE instead). If you care about the rep and vote count, that's arguably a legitimate reason to migrate (although you could question how much the fake Internet points actually matter anyway, especially given that we're only talking about 2 votes), but again, you should vote to migrate with the standard path.

So, I actually agree that there's at least *some* merit to migrating (rather than deleting and reposting), but the case would be a lot stronger if the question was already answered.